# How can I pass a variable into a parallel asynchronous HTTP GET request?

Tags: rust, stream, rust-tokio

I am super new to programming in Rust and I do not understand how to pass a variable into this code. I need to perform parallel asynchronous HTTP GET requests. I do receive the bytes and I would love to save them in folder AAA, BBB, CCC depending on the url. Could you please help?

```
let mut urls:Vec<&str> = vec![];

    urls.push("url1?code=AAA");
    urls.push("url2?code=BBB");
    urls.push("url3?code=CCC");

    let client = Client::new();
    static mut CONTATORE : i32 = 0;

    let bodies = stream::iter(urls)
        .map(|url| {
            let client = client.clone();
            let codice = codice.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                let resp = client.get(url).header("Authorization", codice.clone()).send().await?;

                resp.bytes().await
            })
        })
        .buffered(PARALLEL_REQUESTS);

        
    bodies
        .for_each(|b| async {
            match b {
                Ok(Ok(b)) => {
                    println!("Got {} bytes", b.len());
                    //let my_string = String::from_utf8(b.to_vec()).unwrap();
                    //println!("{}", my_string);                    

                    let mut path: String = "data/esperimenti/".to_string();
//Variable CODE Should be here to save the specific bytes into a specific folder
                    path.push_str(&format!("{}", "CODE")); 
                    path.push_str(&format!("{}", ".json"));
                    
                    
                    
                },
                Ok(Err(e)) => eprintln!("Got a reqwest::Error: {}", e),
                Err(e) => eprintln!("Got a tokio::JoinError: {}", e),
            }
        })
        .await;
```

I tried with an "unsafe" global variable, but I dislike the thing.

Comment: Aside from the answer, the `tokio::spawn` doesn't really seem userful, especially with all the post-processing being out of tasks anyway. You're basically adding the opportunity to parallelise the one thing least needs it because it's all IO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `resp.bytes().await` you can return tuple (or your new type), for example `(resp.bytes().await, "CODE".to_string())` and then consume that return type in `bodies.for_each()`

```rust
use futures; // 0.3.28
use tokio; // 1.29.1

use futures::stream::{StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main()
{
    let bodies = futures::stream::iter(vec!["x".to_string(), "y".to_string(), "z".to_string()]).map(|v| {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            (v, "CODE".to_string())
        })
    }).buffered(2);
    
    bodies.for_each(|v| async {
        if let Ok(v) = v {
            println!("{:?}", v);
        }
    }).await;
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d35e00e18936673e133aa9f6b6872a7